# Swift m3u8 format - timing issue

Tags: ios, swift, m3u8

I converted my video files to .m3u8 because Apple's rules. They are working fine normally. But when I forward the video to a specific time (lets say 2:00) that goes around 4:00 although displaying the time as 2:00. That is same both on Safari and with this code on IOS:

```
AVPlayerVC.player?.currentItem?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(goToThisTime), 60000))
```

That shows current time correctly. But displays the wrong part of the video.

Comment: Do you get better results if you use the `seek` variant that lets you specify tolerances?

Comment: I am sorry but I didnt understand what to change in my code line. I thought I used seek.

Comment: Check the docs; there are various forms of `seek`.  Some of them take extra parameters.

Comment: Ok I will. thanks. But why is it doing the same issue even I try on Safari by using video's location on the server (www.website.com/videos/video1.m3u8). Video is working. But if I forward it by dragging the time bar, that goes wrong part of video.

Comment: It's possible there's something odd about your video...or the conversion.  It's also quite possible that my suggestion will not help.  It's just an idea to try while you're debugging.

Comment: Yes you were right. That was all about the video. I used ffmpeg to create m3u8. And that is working fine now. Should I close this question?